Tomcat http-nio threads are daemon threads
I hit the following endpoint:
@RestController
public static class ThreadTestController {

    @PostMapping("/test")
    private void test() {
        log.info("name: {} daemon: {}", Thread.currentThread().getName(),
            Thread.currentThread().isDaemon());
        Thread.ofPlatform().start(() -> log.info("name: {} daemon: {}", Thread.currentThread().getName(),
            Thread.currentThread().isDaemon()));
    }
}

and I get:
2024-07-30 13:47:52.263 [http-nio-8095-exec-1] [] INFO  t.h.mypackage - name: http-nio-8095-exec-1 daemon: true
2024-07-30 13:47:52.264 [Thread-1] [] INFO  t.h.mypackage - name: Thread-1 daemon: true

Questions:

Why http-nio-8095-exec-1 is a daemon thread?
Does it have anything in common with ForkJoinPool? I read in the Java docs:


All worker threads are initialized with Thread.isDaemon() set true.


Are you asking why Tomcat creates daemon threads? Have you already read Tomcat code?

Yes, that's what I'm asking plus does it have anything in common with ForkJoinPool. I haven't read the Tomcat code.

I've just checked everything under org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded package and I don't see threadpool configuration

I checked all setDaemon(true) in the Tomcat codebase. There is an explicit setDaemon(true) in the nio pool here:
// Start poller thread
poller = new Poller();
Thread pollerThread = new Thread(poller, getName() + "-Poller");
pollerThread.setPriority(threadPriority);
pollerThread.setDaemon(true);
pollerThread.start();


I think it has to be like that because it would not be possible to stop the Tomcat server if the threads were not daemons.
It has nothing to do with ForkJoinPool.
